# delete Q_GLOBAL_STATIC in correct thread

Tags: multithreading, qt, visual-c++, static, qt5

I have an application consisting of an executable and several DLLs.

The exe links a dll statically. This dll creates a worker thread which instantiates a Q_GLOBAL_STATIC object (first access). So this object (derived from QObject) lives in this worker thread.

At program exit this object needs to be destroyed in the worker thread. But it is actually destroyed when the static dll gets unloaded, which is happening in the main thread.

How do I delete this global static object in the correct thread?

I tried manually deleting it when my worker thread finishes. But this results in a crash after my destructor returns.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicit call destructor on that object like this `obj.~Test();` then after check if object is destroyed `obj.isDestroyed()` if it is not working.

Use QLibrary to load and unload dll ( https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qlibrary.html). Where in `Q_GLOBAL_STATIC` documentation(https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qglobalstatic.html#destruction) it is mention that destructor will be called on unload of library or atexit() funciton of application.

Comment: If I manually call the destructor like you suggested, it can execute the clean-up code in the correct thread. But later, when the main thread unloads the statically linked library, QGlobalStatic's destructor calls my destructor again (same `this` pointer). My class inherits from QAbstractItemModel whose destructor tries to use an already invalid QAbstractItemModelPrivate object and crashes.
I cannot use QLibrary because the library is loaded statically.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to share my solution. To make it work, I introduced a simple private class which I use as a QGlobalStatic. This global object of this class holds the real singleton object and allows safe deletion of it in the correct thread.

The header file:

```
class MySingletonPrivate;

class MySingleton : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    static MySingleton* instance();
    static void deleteInstance();
protected:
    MySingleton( QObject *parent = nullptr );
    ~MySingleton();

    friend class MySingletonPrivate;
};
```

The cpp file:

```
class MySingletonPrivate
{
public:
    MySingletonPrivate()
        : inst( new MySingleton() )
    {
        QObject::connect( QThread::currentThread(), &QThread::finished, inst, &MySingleton::deleteLater );
    }
    ~MySingletonPrivate()
    {
        Q_ASSERT( inst.isNull() );
    }
    MySingleton* instance() const
    {
        return inst;
    }
private:
    QPointer< MySingleton > inst;
};

Q_GLOBAL_STATIC( MySingletonPrivate, s_instance );

MySingleton* MySingleton::instance()
{
    return s_instance->instance();
}

void MySingleton::deleteInstance()
{
    delete s_instance->instance();
}
```

Using the signal QThread::finished the global instance is deleted at the end of the worker thread.
I left out the include instructions and the constructor and destructor implemention to make the answer shorter.
Of course, the first call to MySingleton::instance() must happen in the worker thread.